# Where does Eclipse store preferences?

Tags: java, eclipse, formatting, eclipse-rcp, settings

When I change a setting in a window like in the screenshot below, where are those settings actually stored?

Bonus: Is there any way, using Java, Eclipse RCP etc, to access the settings programmatically?

Thanks!

[image: Eclipse Preferences]

Comment: Check your *workspace* folder. There is this *properties.properties* file that can solve your curiosity and a *.metadata* folder as well.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Source : [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#Where_are_Eclipse_preferences_stored.3F)

If you want to keep preferences from one version to the other, export them using File/Export/Preferences.

Preferences are stored in various places (this applies to Eclipse 3.1)

for each installation (but this may vary for multi-user installations), in files stored in:
        `<eclipse_home>/eclipse/configuration/.settings/`

There is typically one file per plugin, with a prefs extension. Note that very few plug-ins use installation-wide preferences.

for each workspace, in files stored in `<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` .

There is typically one file per plugin, with a prefs extension.
for each project --for project-level settings -- in files stored in a .settings sub-directory of your project folder.

[Here's](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Preferences/article.html) the article to access preferences using java code.

Comment: That article is from 2002, is it still relevant?

Comment: On the mac, the <eclipse_home> type path one is at:

`/Applications/Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/configuration/.settings`

Comment: If anyone reading this has enough rep for a 1-character edit, there is now an https version of the URL in the second link.

Answer (score 11):

The preferences are stored in prefs files in the workspace at  `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings`. There is one prefs-file for each plugin contributing preferences.

The programmatical access to the entire preferences is done with `IPreferencesService` the which you may obtain using `Platform.getPreferencesService()`.

You may find more information and examples on how to use them in the [Runtime preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_preferences.htm) Eclipse help page.

Answer (score 6):

Search for it:

Change some setting in Eclipse then run:

```
find ~  -type f -mmin -5 | grep "\.settings"
```

This will discover files modified in last 5 minutes.

Mine was in `workspace`, literally...

```
~/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
```

Comment: Ah! This is a great way to find the change - thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see most of the relevant eclipse settings (mainly for JDT) in the **[saneclipse](http://www.saneclipse.com/)** project from [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/people/larsvogel.html).

See the [`vogellacompany/com.vogella.saneclipse`](https://github.com/vogellacompany/com.vogella.saneclipse) repo, which will tweak and fine-tune the settings of:

```
com.vogella.saneclipse.preferences/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
com.vogella.saneclipse.preferences/.settings/org.eclipse.core.runtime.prefs
com.vogella.saneclipse.preferences/.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs
com.vogella.saneclipse.templates/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
com.vogella.saneclipse.fileextensions/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs
com.vogella.saneclipse.fileextensions/.settings/org.eclipse.pde.core.prefs
```