# move eclipse to another computer while keeping its configurations

Tags: java, eclipse

I have installed some plugins into my eclipse, and change lots of configurations, such as 
change default Perspective, hide some items in tool bar...

now, I want to share this "whole eclipse" with others by simply copying 
the install package of my eclipse, and deliver to others.

However, when I run this copy on another computer first time, it doesn't open the
'default perspective' which I've set on my own computer, instead, it open the 'java EE' 
perspective.

what's more, some items which I've hiden on my own computer now appears.
 Another issue is my previous workspace doesn't exit on the new computer, 
an error occurs.

what should I do to ensure the copy works well(same behaviors as the old one) on 
another computer, for example, put something like xxx.config into the install pakage?

background:I have developed some plugins for my eclipse,  and I want to deliver this eclipse as  a "product" to others, so that they can make use of it. Is it a good way simply deliver them a copy of my install pakage?

Comment: Sometimes when you have some specific variables inside `eclipse.ini` file you need to update them(i.e. vm) - but it shouldn't cause any problems.

Comment: I have the same challenge.  Tried to copy .settings, .project .classpath this does not seem to work, I am reading, searching, and learning what's the best way.

Answer (score 5):

Generally eclipse stores all its configuration under workspace. So, you have to copy your current workspace folder to any location you want and everything should work. Even if your projects are in different location and eclipse will not be able to open then just open eclipse and delete old project. All other configurations should remain.

Comment: ye.. but how can I share "everything" with others? you see, there're different versions of eclipse, kepler, lunar, when I start a specific one, they just behave differently.

Comment: You can share your workspace. I do not think however that this is a good idea. Workspace is a kind of private, custom data. It for example contains colors, size and location of views etc. Compatibility of eclipse versions is separate issue. There are however specific conf. files that can and should be shared. For example xml file that contains definition of warnings produceced by eclipse should be shared among team members.

Comment: Didn't inport .project file.

Answer (score 2):

Try this in eclipse. File->Export->Preferences. This will save prefernces file to disk. In your new work-space, just import this file.

Comment: em...not the exactly way I want. Cause I want to deliver it completely, so that when others first startup, they have no need to do jobs like "import".after all, I will be annoyed if I have to import something before I can use a product of eclipse.@Pranalee

Comment: I agree. But can you please first try if this works for you. If yes, we can figure out way to ship this file by default

Comment: Also see this thread might be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431989/where-does-eclipse-store-preferences

Comment: I've try your first approach, and I use"export all" option, and it turns out to be not working...It just open the "java ee"perspective, not the one I've set in previous workspace.@Pranalee